# Is it possible to highlight strings in a *.txt file using Java?

Tags: java, text-editor

I wrote a "search" function as part of a program I'm working on. At the moment, I have it set to output where it found the searched word (every occurrence) to the console. What I want it to do now is open the file in Notepad (already know how) and to highlight every occurrence of the searched word.

Everywhere I've looked I see frames and text-areas, which is no good for me at the moment because I don't know any GUI coding yet.

Comment: How would you "highlight" in notepad?

Comment: The only way I know how to highlight is to click-drag when you open Notepad directly. What I'm after is for my program's search function to highlight specified text, much like Notepad's built in "find" function.

Comment: @JoshuaNapier and BTW, GUI can be easily created using IDEs like NetBeans. You just need to put all the required components at proper place use the library functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The txt fileformat does not support any kind of formatting, so you cannot highlight anything in the traditional way.** So the options you are left with is:

- you can use *underscores*
- or you can use FULL-UPPERCASE
- or you can use ** stars **

or similar approaches that depend on basic characters available in the used characterset.

Comment: So I'll never achieve a result similar to that of Notepad's "find" function?

Comment: No. Notepad (the GUI) can highlight part of the text for you, but you have no way to instruct the program (Notepad) to do it *via the textfile*. To highlight a part of the text, you would need to somehow mark it in a way that Notepad recognizes it, and unfortunately the TXT fileformat does not support any kind of feature for that.

Answer (score 1):

*Short answer: **NO***

**Backdoor**: Create your own Notepad like java app using swing that will support the required features. You may say that creating this app is teadious but who says you have to create all the features...Just the basic ones will be fine.